# Determining the appropriate size for a TFS data tier VM

Tags: sql-server-2008, tfs, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a two-tier (app tier/data tier) TFS 2010 installation. The data tier is currently living on a box that is being used for other things aside from TFS. My plan is to move to a VM which would be dedicated solely to TFS. It'll run SQL 2008 R2 and SSRS, with only TFS and SharePoint databases being on the box.

My questions are:

1. What metrics should be captured to determine the load on the server?
2. Are there any other things that should be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of projects , size of projects check in frequency # of branches per project and number of developers per project. Last environment I had set up was 60 teams 5 - 8 branches per team with an average of 10-15 developers heavy usage running on an 8 core 48 gb server no issues.

Comment: Disk io is the biggest one

Comment: I'm not dealing with that many teams, but there is a pretty good amount of activity. Thus far my research has lead me to 8 core 16 gbs.

Comment: I would set aside money for additional memory if you need it. Fast disks and a room for both history and file growth and you should be set.

Comment: Any other info that you might need? Or did this gap help to resolve your issue?

Comment: One other concern that I have is around snapshots. When it comes time to upgrade to TFS 2013, I'd like to be able to create a snapshot of the box before the upgrade. That's one of the reasons why I want to virtualize. Since I'm going to have 4 drives (C - OS, E - Temp, F - Log, G - Data), I'm not sure how the whole snapshot thing will work for me.

Comment: One of the best places to find up to the moment information about everything TFS http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/ Microsoft TFS Project Manager

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I think I have everything I need now.